# how to change background color of quick select range button in ngx-bootstrap bsdatepicker (angular)?

Tags: javascript, angular, ngx-bootstrap, ngx-daterangepicker-material

I want to change the background color of quick select ranges buttons in bsdatepicker.
Where should i actually make change to change background color of those buttons highlighted in below image.

[Daterangepicker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WOxzx.png)

[Daterangepicker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYUSO.png)

Comment: Use CSS.  If it's only one one component, put it into that component's CSS file.  If it's for the whole app, put it in a global CSS file. To figure out what CSS classes are being applied, right-click the button in Chrome, click Inspect Element.  You'll see the CSS classes applied to those buttons or their parents.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Issue solved by making changes in css files from node_modules.
I had to change css files related to bs-datepicker from node_modules folder.
Thanks @funkMonkey. I got the css file name by inspecting element.

Comment: Hi Kanhaiya, It's a mistake to edit the CSS files of a node module.  The next time you update the module to a new version, or someone else checks out your code and runs npm install, or just when you deploy the application to a server, your changes will be overwritten.  Instead, you should override those styles in your own code, like I said above: do it in either a components CSS file or a application-wide CSS file.